# Spring Annotation based scheduler i.e '@Scheduled' is not running continuously as per cron expression

Tags: java, spring, cron, annotations, scheduler

I have used Spring Annotation based scheduler `@Scheduler` and set it to run for every 30 
    seconds. My sample code is something like this.

This is a sample Service code to use Scheduler annotation.

```
 @Service
    public class SchedulerJob
    {
        @Scheduled(cron="*/30 * * * * ?")
        public void demoServiceMethod()
        {
            System.out.println("Job running every 30 seconds");
        }
    }
```

The above code is working fine and is running for every 30 seconds, but sometimes it is not 
    running. 
    When i restart the server, it is picking up again.

Can anyone tell me the reason for this kind of behaviour with the @Scheduler annotation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As my job is running for every 30 seconds, how can i make it to wait untill previous triggered job is completed i.e i don't want new job to get triggered untill previous triggered job is completed?

Comment: The fixedDelay property makes sure that there is a delay of n millisecond between the finish time of an execution of a task and the start time of the next execution of the task.

This property is specifically useful when we need to make sure that only one instance of the task runs all the time. For dependent jobs, it is quite helpful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set Spring configuration with the annotation  `@EnableScheduling`

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class RootConfig { .. }
```

A cron-like expression, extend the usual UNIX definition to include triggers on the second as well as minute, hour, day of month, month and day of week. e.g. "0 * * * * MON-FRI" means once per minute onweekdays.

`cron` has a 60 seconds of granularity, itsn't the best tool to use. If you run it that often, cron does not go down to sub-minute resolutions, you will need to find another way.

Try to use the expression `initialDelayString` defines the milliseconds to delay before the first execution and `fixedDelayString` execute the annotated method with a fixed period in milliseconds between the end of the last invocation and the start of the next.

```
@Scheduled(initialDelayString = "${initialDelayString}", fixedDelayString = "${fixedDelayString}")
public void demoServiceMethod()
```

Comment: _The above code is working fine and is running for every 30 seconds, but sometimes it is not running._ Presumably they already have `@EnableScheduling`, if it's working most times.

Comment: Also, are you suggesting Spring uses `cron`? This is wrong. It uses its own scheduler that interprets those cron expressions. It's not limited to `cron` granularity.